# ¿Cuál es el análisis gramatical de la siguiente frase?

Tags: gramática, objetos-directos, se

Estaba escribiendo una receta de cómo preparar la sopa, tratando de usar [las formas impersonales de los verbos](http://www.spanishdict.com/topics/show/86) (por ejemplo, ***Se necesita*** calentar el agua). Cuando la mostré a mis amigos hispanohablantes me dijeron que esta versión suena raro:

> Si el repollo es demasiado duro, *se puede* colocar**lo** incluso antes de las papas.

Y que hay que escribirla así (sin **lo**):

> Si el repollo es demasiado duro, *se puede* colocar incluso antes de las papas.

Pero cuando uno cambia la frase, por ejemplo, usando la segunda persona del singular del verbo *poder*, aparece el objeto directo **lo**:

> Si el repollo es demasiado duro, *puedes* colocar**lo** incluso antes de las papas.

o

> Si el repollo es demasiado duro, *podemos* colocar**lo** incluso antes de las papas.

¿Cuál es la regla gramatical que corresponde a este caso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema con la primera frase no es que sobre el **lo**, si no el uso redundante del pronombre *"lo"* y el *"se"*, que puede ser entendido también como pronombre.

En la segunda frase

> Si el repollo es demasiado duro, **se** puede colocar incluso antes de de las papas.

Has eliminado el pronombre **"lo"** que se refiere al repollo, por el *"se"*, que en este caso es un *"se" impersonal* (el "se" se convierte en una partícula que esconde al agente de la acción: aquel que coloca el repollo). Pero *"se"* puede hacer también de pronombre y referir al complemento indirecto, y podría ir también tras el verbo, como va el *"lo"* en los otros ejemplos.

> Si el repollo es demasiado duro, puede colocar**se** incluso antes de de las papas.

Date cuenta de que en las dos últimas frases puedes cambiar el *"lo"* de posición, ya que es un simple pronombre.

> Si el repollo es demasiado duro, **lo** puedes/podemos colocar incluso antes de de las papas.
>
> Si el repollo es demasiado duro, **se** puede colocar incluso antes de de las papas.

y tendría el mismo valor que el *"se"*, y puede ir con el verbo *poder* (No es obligatorio user *"lo"* con *poder*), aunque en este caso sea un *"se" impersonal*, y no un pronombre.

El uso "obligatorio" de *"lo"* viene con la conjugación en segunda persona (puedes/podemos) ya que entonces no tiene cabida el uso de *"se" impersonal* o como pronombre, porque el repollo sería entonces el complemento directo, y usamos *"lo"* y no *"le"* o *"se"*.

Comment: Un ejemplo análogo: `Si el repollo es muy frágil, se puede romper` -- `Si el repollo es muy frágil, puedes romperlo`.

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de Diego es correcta. Añado que la ambigüedad del "se" en este caso implica que la primera frase no es incorrecta, aunque la segunda sea (marginalmente) preferible.

Que no es incorrecta se puede comprobar cambiando de lugar el "lo":

> Si el repollo es demasiado duro, se puede **colocarlo**  incluso antes de las papas.
>
> Si el repollo es demasiado duro, se **lo** puede colocar incluso antes de las papas.

Es equivalente, y suena un poco menos rara. Porque la inmediatez del "lo" deja más en claro que el "se" es impersonal.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es el sujeto de la oración. en el segundo y tercer caso:

> (Tú) puedes colorcalo...
>
> (Nosotros) podemos colocarlo....

El sujeto es la persona y se usa el objeto directo "lo" para identificar que lo que podemos colocar es el repollo.
Por el contrario en la primera oración el sujeto es el repollo:

> (El repollo) se puede colocar...

por lo tanto no es correcto usar el objeto directo "lo".